# How to create an object with Function interface field from input file (JAVA 8)?

Tags: java, function, interface

I am currently making a simple trading card game using java.
First of all, I have a class called `Card`. This is the main component of my game. Each card will have a special ability that can be invoked during the game. I create this ability as a `function interface`, as follow:

```
public class Card { 
  private String name;
  private int originalValue;
  private int currentValue;
  public Function<Aftermath, Ability> abilityProvider;

  .... }
```

Is it possible to create this Card object using an input file (e.q. JSON)? 
If so, how do I populate the `abilityProvider`?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that has to be a thing _you build and choose_, not something there's some universal answer for.

Comment: A function is *logic* (code). Did you intend to put Java code in the JSON? Did you intend the JSON Parser to *compile* that code for you? What did you *intend* the JSON to be?

Comment: I am thinking a way to create an object with Function Interface as one of its fields from an input file. I might not be able to use JSON.

Comment: I am open to any suggestion (e.g. changing the structure of my class)